# AWS Amplify listUsersInGroup throws a networking error only on IOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I'm build an app using Expo - react native. For the user authentication i'm using AWS amplify and all users are put into different groups automatically based on a lambda function. When i try to call the AWS AdminQueries '/listUsersInGroup' it works fine on both android and web. But on IOS i get a network error. I'm running expo 48.0.0 with react-native 0.71.5 on an iphone 14 simulator.

Any help in regards to further debugging would be awesome. The exact same request works fine on IOS when using the fetch api instead of AWS amplify API.

This is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, Pressable, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

import { Amplify, Auth, API } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from '../../aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

export default function EmployeesCultureplace(){

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const [user, setUser] = useState()
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
  const [employees,setEmployees] = useState([])
  const [hasAnyUsers,setHasAnyUsers] = useState(null);

  const [tempText, setTempText] = useState("no employees")


  let prepare = async () => {
    try {
      let userData = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('user'))
      setUser(userData)
      setHasAnyUsers(null)
      setEmployees([])

      return userData
    } catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    } finally {
      setIsReady(true)
    } 
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    prepare().then((user) => {
      listUsers(user).then((e) => {
        setEmployees(user)
      }).catch((e) => {
        // here we catch the error
        console.log("ERROR")
        console.log(e)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
      })
    })

  },[])
 
  // THIS IS THE FUNCTION that's giving alot of issues
  let nextToken;
  let listUsers = async (user) => {
    let apiName = 'AdminQueries';
    let path = '/listUsersInGroup';

    let myInit = { 
      queryStringParameters: {
        "groupname": [(user["custom:group"])]
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        Authorization: `${(await Auth.currentSession()).getAccessToken().getJwtToken()}`
      }
  }
  const { NextToken, ...rest } =  await API.get(apiName, path, myInit);
  nextToken = NextToken;
  return rest;
}
   

  return (
  <></>
    
  )
}
```

This is the error, that only appears on IOS:
In short terms the errors writes [Error: Network Error] with the following stack trace:

```
{
"message":"Network Error",
"name":"Error",
"stack":"Error: Network Error\n    at createError (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=dk.project.sub:238728:26)\n    
at handleError (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=dk.project.sub:238650:27)\n    at call (native)\n    
at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=dk.project.sub:31717:31)\n    
at setReadyState (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=dk.project.sub:30442:33)\n    
at __didCompleteResponse (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=dk.project.sub:30253:29)\n    
at apply (native)\n    
at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=dk.project.sub:30378:52)\n    
at apply (native)\n    
at emit (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=dk.project.sub:2278:40)\n    
at apply (native)\n    
at __callFunction (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=dk.project.sub:2812:36)\n    
at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=dk.project.sub:2573:31)\n    
at __guard (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=dk.project.sub:2763:15)\n    
at callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=dk.project.sub:2572:21)",
"config":
{"transitional":{
"silentJSONParsing":true,
"forcedJSONParsing":true,
"clarifyTimeoutError":false
},
"transformRequest":[null],
"transformResponse":[null],
"timeout":0,
"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN",
"xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN",
"maxContentLength":-1,
"maxBodyLength":-1,
"headers":{
"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
"User-Agent":"aws-amplify/5.1.5 react-native",
"Content-Type":"application/json",
"Authorization":"TOKENXXX",
"method":"get",
"url":"https://xxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/listUsersInGroup?groupname=project",
"host":"xxxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
"path":"/dev/listUsersInGroup",
"data":"null",
"responseType":"json",
"cancelToken":{"promise":{"_h":1,"_i":0,"_j":null,"_k":{"onRejected":null,"promise":{"_h":0,"_i":0,"_j":null,"_k":null}}},"_listeners":[null]}},"status":null}
```

Comment: Use the reactiva-native-debugger (https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) and inspect the network request/response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this same issue and the solution for me was making sure that `Content-Type` in the header was set to `'Content-Type': 'Application/json'`

For some reason it was set to `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

I guess it is case sensitive on iOS but not Android.